# Creating diverging arrows with text

Tags: arrowwithtext

I need to create something like this. I have difficulty in creating the arrows with text above and below.
Are you able to code the entire expression for me?

[image: diverging and converging arrows]

Thank you,
Andrea

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: This appears to be a prime examle for [TikZ/PGF](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=de). I can very much recommend taking a look into the documentation since it provides plenty of detailed examples with great explanations. I guess for your needs, the explanations in the Chapters 16 and 17 are what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. I checked the manual but it looks a bit complicated and I'd just need to do something like that. I'd appreciate it if someone could post an example of the code to do it as shown above. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun a solution with `tikz-cd`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzcdset{every arrow/.append style = -{Latex[scale=2.5]}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=.5cm, column sep=2cm]
& 200 \arrow[rd] & \\
193^2 \arrow[ru, "+7"] \arrow[rd, "-7"'] & & {37{,}200+7^2=37{,}249} \\
& 186 \arrow[ru] &                    
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

..or you can use this different solution....

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz,diagrams={line width=2pt,>={Stealth[round,length=10pt,width=5pt,inset=1pt]}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=-.05cm, column sep=1.5cm]
& 200 \arrow[rd] & \\
193^2 \arrow[ru, "+7"] \arrow[rd, "-7"'] & &  {37{,}200+7^2=37{,}249} \\
& 186 \arrow[ru] &                    
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That's what I needed. The only problem for me is that I need to put it in Roam Research and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @AndreaNagar Hi, you're welcome. :-) But what is Roam Research? I not know this software. But my job with LaTeX works correctly. Can you explain me what is the problem, please?